# Tweet/Facebook Button Broken in IE9?

Tags: header, internet-explorer-9, blogger

Here's a picture of the problem: http://i55.tinypic.com/29g0izc.jpg

Problem Site: http://windowsphonedaily.blogspot.com/

I have my tweet and like button setup at the header of each new article underneath the title. It works extremely well with Chrome and Firefox. But I noticed that in IE9 both buttons are forced to the left and that the actual tweet button is missing. You can see in the above picture the comparison between FF4, Chrome 11, and IE9.

Does anyone know how to fix this without breaking it in the other browsers? Here is the code I have used to set up the buttons.

```
<div class='post-header'>
<table>
<div class='post-header-line-1'/>
    <!-- Facebook's Like Button -->
    <div style='float:right;'>
        <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'/><fb:like font='arial' href='' layout='button_count' show_faces='false' width='10'/></div>
    <!-- Twitter's Tweet Button -->
    <div style='float:right;'><a class='twitter-share-button' data-count='horizontal' data-via='WinPhoneDaily' href='http://twitter.com/share'>Tweet</a><script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' type='text/javascript'/></div>

  <span class='post-author vcard'>
    <b:if cond='data:top.showAuthor'>
      <data:top.authorLabel/>
      <span class='fn'><data:post.author/></span>
    </b:if>
  </span> <span class='post-timestamp'>
    <b:if cond='data:top.showTimestamp'>
      <data:top.timestampLabel/>
    <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
      <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
    </b:if>
    </b:if>
  </span></table>
```

Comment: Please add screenshot to question instead of link, and screenshot of current look of site too. Your blog seems private.